# Wemos D1 R2 and I2C scanning with LCD 1602

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm unable to use the 1602 LCD connected with an I2C controller to my Wemos D1 R2 because it seems to be unvisible to the board. I've tried serveral I2C scanner but I always get the same feedback: "No devices found".
I've connected the controller to the Wemos in this way: *GND->GND, VCC->5V, SDA->SDA/D2, SCL->SCL/D1*.

The I2C controller and the LCD are perfectly running with my Arduino UNO (I got the *0x3F* I2C address).

Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: address should be the same, make sure the pins are configured correctly (D1!=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [Wemos D1 R2 V2.1.0](https://www.wemos.cc/product/d1.html) (the black board) instead of the [Wemos D1 R2](http://www.banggood.com/it/WeMos-D1-R2-WiFi-ESP8266-Development-Board-Compatible-Arduino-UNO-Program-By-Arduino-IDE-p-1011870.html) (the blue one) the I2C scanner successfully finds the LCD and my sketch runs without any troubles.